# Should I alter my schedule to daven Minchah with a minyan?

Tags: tefilla, tzibur-community, minyan, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Is it better to wait to daven Minchah K’tanah if there’s a chance one could be finished working before sunset? Or is it okay to daven Minchah Gedolah and join the minyan for Ma’ariv, even though one can’t help make the minyan for Minchah?

Related questions:

- [Can one be counted in a minyan if one has already davened?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48155/can-one-be-counted-in-a-minyan-if-one-has-already-davened)
- [Priority of Davening with a Minyan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49/priority-of-davening-with-a-minyan)

Comment: Confirming: You would be davening Mincha Gedola without a Minyan? Is that your query?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yes. Say one's schedule is such that one must usually — but not always — work past sunset, and the most natural thing is to daven Minchah Gedolah alone after midday.

Comment: [לייטי עלה במערבא אמאן דמצלי עם דמדומי חמה מאי טעמא דלמא מיטרפא ליה שעתא](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.29b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)