# Is it better to do a Mitzvah now or delay to do it better (with more Hiddur) later on?

Tags: mitzvah, beauty

If one can do a Mitzvah now in an acceptable fashion but can do it better (with Hiddur) later on is it better to wait to do it B'Hiddur? I seem to recall that there is a Gemara somewhere from where we learn from Dovid Hamelech that it is better to do the Mitzvah right away and not wait but I can't remember where. I guess the question revolves around what is more important Zerizus or Shlaimus.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49/170 & its answers.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13421/759

Answer (score 10):

The Terumas Hadeshen ([#35](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%9F/%D7%90/%D7%9C%D7%94)) discusses delaying Kiddush Levana in order to fulfill the obligation in it's *hiddur* on Motze Shabbos. He discusses whether it is worth delaying a mitzvah for it's *hiddur*, and rules:

> דכל היכא דראוי הוא להסתפק שתעבור המצוה אין משהין אותה אפילו כדי
> לעשותה יותר מן המובחר  ומ"מ מוכח התם דדוקא בדראוי להסתפק שתעבור המצוה
> אז לא משהינן לה אבל בשאין ראוי להסתפק לא

In summary, unless there is a suspicion that by waiting it out, you may lose the oppurtunity of fulfilling the mitzva, it is worth delaying to accomplish the *hiddur*. This is quoted by Rema (OC 426) [see also Biur HaGra, who disagrees IIRC].

However, the Chayei Adam ([Nishmas Adam 68:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Nishmat_Adam.68.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi)) quotes the Sefer Chassidim ([878](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.878.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that one should not put off fulfilling a mitzvah immediately in order to achieve *hiddur* at a later point, and rules accordingly.

This is the quote from the Sefer Chassidim.

> כתיב (תהלים קיט ס) חשתי ולא התמהמהתי לשמור מצותיך לא יעכב אדם את המצוה
> בעבור זה שאמרה תורה זה אלי ואנוהו התנאה לפניו במצות כגון טלית נאה וספר
> תורה נאה שלא יאמר אדם כיון שיש לי טלית לקנות אמתין עד שיבוא לידי טלית
> יפה מאוד אלא יקנה מיד טלית אע"פ שאינה יפה כל כך. וכן עיר שאין בה ס"ת
> ויש שם סופר שיודע בדוקא לכתוב אבל אינו יודע לכתוב כל כך יפה כמו סופר
> אחר שלא בא כל כך בקרוב זמן מוטב שיכתוב אותו המצוי מיד אע"פ שאינו כותב
> יפה כי על זה נא' חשתי ולא התמהמהתי לשמור מצותיך:

See also Sdei Chemed (מערכת ב' כלל ז' אות א'), who discusses the various opinions on whether it is worth pushing off a mitzvah to gain ברוב עם הדרת מלך, or תדיר קודם. There is also a discussion in the Poskim (Pre Megadim) whether it is worth pushing off fulfilling a Mitzvah to gain מצוה בו יותר מבשלוחו.

Comment: Great well rounded response! I tried looking at the Sefer Chasidim (876) but could not find it at that location. Is it perhaps a typo?

Comment: @joeh Indeed a typo. It's in 878. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: These are good sources, but they discuss different cases. The term "hiddur" is something used very loosely nowadays, but there's no real reason to think the "benefit" of saying Kiddush Levana on Saturday night should have the same rule as the "benefit" gained by having a prettier mitzva object. Every potential "hiddur" needs to be evaluated on its own merits.

Comment: DoubleAA - I agree. The Chochmas Odam appears to equate these two, because he understands the Terumas Hadeshen and the Sefer Chassidim to be arguing.

Answer (score 1):

[R. Tzadok Ha-Kohen of Lublin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zadok_HaKohen) was asked this exact question by [R. Leibel Eiger](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8). When serving as the sandek for a bris, R. Leibel would spend hours preparing and thus delay the bris. However, as a result the bris would be performed as a greater "mitzvah min ha-muvchar." In his response, R. Tzadok quoted the Terumas Ha-Deshen, who said that performing a mitzvah min ha-muvchar has precedence over zerizus. See the teshuvah [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9159&st=&pgnum=47&hilite=).

However, R. Asher Weiss [quotes](https://www.torahbase.org/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA/) the Panim Meiros and Aruch Ha-Shulchan, as well as the Gra and Bach, who disagree with the ruling of the Terumas Ha-Deshen:

> ובשבות יעקב [ח"א סי' ל"ד] נשאל, במי שיש לו אתרוג שאינו הדר כ"כ, ויודע
> שלאחר זמן יבוא לידו אתרוג מהודר טפי הי מינייהו עדיף זריזין מקדימין או
> דילמא הידור מצוה עדיף טפי, ופסק, דהיכא שספק אי יבוא לידו אתרוג מהודר
> טפי מצוה לברך על אתרוג שלו אף שאינו הדר כ"כ, אבל כשיודע בבירור שיבוא
> לידו אתרוג יפה יותר עדיף שימתין דהידור מצוה עדיף מזריזין מקדימין,
> ובשו"ת דברי מלכיאל [ח"א סי' י"ב] כתב דשרי לדחות מצוה כדי לקיימה בהידור
> כשם שמותר להלין את המת משום כבודו, הרי דנקטו כהתרוה"ד והרמ"א. אולם,
> בפנים מאירות [ח"ב סי' א'] פליג ע"ד התרוה"ד, וכן בערוך השולחן [שם סי'
> תכ"ו] נקט עיקר דעדיף טפי לקדש הלבנה בזמן הראשון הראוי לברכה, וכן נהג
> הגר"א ולא המתין למוצ"ש [מעשה רב קנ"ט], ובאמת זה שיטת הב"ח שם עי"ש.]

Comment: This probably could be a comment to the other answer...

Comment: This is a very loose usage of "mitzva min hamuvchar"

Comment: @DoubleAA see the teshuvah for discussion of that point

Comment: For more on this episode, see אות ד here https://www.torahbase.org/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA/

Comment: Presumably the rabbi of Lublin who objected was https://isheiisrael.wordpress.com/2019/01/13/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99/